# Unable to boot Windows after installing OpenSUSE

Tags: windows, boot, mbr, gpt

At my side I having issue that I never faced before, I am unable to boot Windows at my laptop. Simply, whenever I re-install Windows from USB after selecting hard-drive as booting device it says 'Missing Operating System'. I have tried re-installing Windows 10 & Windows 8.1, everytime giving same result. I will describe how it all happened.

At beginning of my journey I had basically default partition set: - Windows 10, System reserved (default system partitions) (NTFS) - Storage Partition (NTFS)

After a while I found out that I can update Windows 10 to Anniversary Update(mentioning this, because I encountered topics where after updates, users could not boot into Windows), to which I proceeded. After update everything worked fine.

Then few days later I decided to install OpenSUSE, to do that I shrinked (C:) partition from 113 gb to 73gb. I had 40 gb free space, on which I setup OpenSUSE with swap partition. During installation bootloader GRUB2, said that it cannot install on EFI partition(error?), so I decided to install on my Hard Drive(selected ATAHDD500...)(I guess MBR). I always did like this, when I was installing Ubuntu, Debian or anything else.

Everything was fine, until I decided to switch to Windows 10. I have selected Windows 10 entry menu at grub2 and it said 'invalid signature' error. Ofcourse I googled to try to save Win 10 partition, but all suggestions did not lead me anywhere.

I decided to re-create all partitions, but first created backup from C:\ using Windows 10 Troubleshoot > commands prompt > notepad. I wiped out all unnecesary partitions(including OpenSuse installation). It looked like this: - Free Space (113gb) - Storage Partition (352gb)

As usually, Windows installer set up all necesary partitions and proceeded for installation. At the end of installation, I removed USB stick and at boot menu selected HDD. Next message that appeared - 'Missing Operating System'. I though, maybe something with usb stick, so I re-created bootable installation on another one, same error appeared.

I tried fixing MBR with Bootrec /fixMbr /fixBoot, but no result. Also I tried installing with UEFI and/or Legacy Support enabled, still same issue.

After all I decided to install Ubuntu Gnome 16.04, I figured out that I can boot on it, only If I install it on enabled UEFI and skip creating partition for EFI, and after all this I have to disable UEFI in BIOS, only then I can successfully boot into Ubuntu, otherwise black screen without any hope for boot.

Right now my ideas are that maybe HDD is damaged and is needed to be fully reformated and scanned for bad blocks. I have done a lot of operations to it including(shrinking, extending).

Also I am quite not sure what is EFI technology and thought maybe somewhere on motherboard is saved boot settings(in boot menu there appears 'Windows Boot Manager', 'Ubuntu', 'MacOsx' - this was added when I was installing hackintosh), so maybe I need just to reset it. Also I want to mention that my HDD has GPT format.

Running this on Laptop Lenovo Flex 14-2, hard drive - Toshiba.

Can you please suggest me any solution that I could try. Using Ubuntu is quite not good solution for me.

tl;dr: After installing Windows 10, it shows 'Missing operating system'

Comment: Have you booted into repair and opened command prompt used diskpart to set your boot partition?

Comment: you mean by setting it `active` ?